# Swift: Subclassing a UIViewController's root view

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift

tl;dr: How can I tell Swift that I'm overriding `MyViewController`'s `view` property with a subclass of `UIView`?

---

### What I'd like to do

I'm a big fan of providing a subclass of `UIView` for a `UIViewController`'s view. For example:

```
// MyView --------------------------------------------------------

@interface MyView: UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;    
@end

@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

// MyViewController ----------------------------------------------

@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyView *view;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.tableView.dataSource = self;
    // etc.
}

@end
```

This is great because it separates the view creation and layout logic from the view controller. Ok, fine.

Near as I can figure, this translates into Swift like so:

```
// MyView --------------------------------------------------------

class MyView: UIView {
    let tableView: UITableView!

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        tableView = UITableView(frame: frame)
    }
}

// MyViewController ----------------------------------------------

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    override func loadView() {
        view = MyView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this causes the compiler to complain with:
        // 'UIView' does not have a member named 'tableView'
        self.view.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

The trouble is I can't seem to figure out how to tell the view controller that its `view` is an instance of `MyView` rather than `UIView` itself.

### Failed attempts

Here's what I've tried so far:

I've tried this at the top of `MyViewController`, with the following error:

```
override var view: MyView!
// error: Cannot override mutable property 'view' of
//        type 'UIView' with covariant type 'MyView!'
```

I've tried this in `loadView`, but no luck:

```
view = MyView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds) as MyView
// this produces the same error as in the original code:
// 'UIView' does not have a member named 'tableView'
```

### So here's the question

How can I tell Swift that I'm overriding `MyViewController`'s `view` property with one of subclass `MyView`? Is this even possible? If not, why not?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the exact same implementation may not be possible in Swift. From the Swift book section about overriding properties:

> “You must always state both the name and the type of the property you
>   are overriding, to enable the compiler to check that your override
>   matches a superclass property with the same name and type.”

However, you could use a computed property that returns a typecast version of your view controller's `view` property, and it would be almost as clean:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    var myView: MyView! { return self.view as MyView }

    override func loadView() {
        view = MyView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myView.tableView.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Shame that there is no way to change `view` class. What if we make another subclass of this controller? Following that patter, we should create something like `myMyView`... Only solution that comes to my mind, is to write getter `func view() -> MyView` and when we need to subclass again we can write `override func view() -> MyAnotherView`. The downside is that we get to our view with `self.view()`.

Comment: This just gives me a black view...doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Apple even use a similar approach themselves in `UITableViewController`. That controller has a property `tableView` that returns exactly the same view as the controller's `view` property, just cast as a `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

can we use something like this?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

weak var viewAlias: UIScrollView!

override func loadView() {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    viewAlias = scrollView

    view = scrollView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    //super.viewDidLoad()
    viewAlias.delegate = self
    viewAlias.contentSize = view.frame.size

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```